# Изменение current_timestamp

Tags: база-данных, mysql

Есть таблица комментариев. В ней часто изменяется значение likes из-за этого изменяется time, что приводит к неправильной выборке комментариев по time. Как сделать, что-бы time не менялся при изменении like, а менялся только при создании комментария

```
id        int(11)   PRIMARY               
id_author int(11)           
id_post   int(11)                    
time      timestamp   CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP      
text      text  utf8_general_ci          
likes     int(11)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

убрать ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP?